# How do I create child views with elements inside?

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, parent-child

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55wLsaWpQ4g&list=FLXYFpBAoGV6fnEzA4Q33klQ&index=4) by google that demonstrated animated transitions with the creation of child views by using `onClick` to add or remove the child view. As part of the learning process: I took the code, broke it down, and made some changes (I am not a copy and paste programmer).

My question is: How do I add a `TextView`, `Button` and other various elements to the child view when it is created?

(Project download from google if you're interested: [full project](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?q=http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/LayoutTransChanging.zip&session_token=otbCuYH_Rp5L4C2a3ROZrcuAlUl8MTM2OTA3ODYwNUAxMzY4OTkyMjA1))

Here is what I have in my activity:

```
/**
 * Custom view painted with a random background color and two different sizes which are
 * toggled between due to user interaction.
 */
public class ColoredView extends View {

    private boolean mExpanded = false;

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mCompressedParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams mExpandedParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);

    private ColoredView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        int red = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
        int green = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random() * 128 + 127);
        int color = 0xff << 24 | (red << 16) |
                (green << 8) | blue;
        setBackgroundColor(color);

        setLayoutParams(mCompressedParams);


        setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Size changes will cause a LayoutTransition animation if the CHANGING transition is enabled
                setLayoutParams(mExpanded ? mCompressedParams : mExpandedParams);
                mExpanded = !mExpanded;
                requestLayout();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I also have this in the `onCreate` method for showing the animations

```
LayoutTransition transition = eventContainer.getLayoutTransition();
    transition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
```

This is my XML which has the `LinearLayout` in which all child views are created in:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/eventContainer">
    </LinearLayout>
```

By adding a button or an edittext to the linearlayout it treats it as an entirely new view, only allowing one object per. Is there a way I could slam a bunch of objects into that ONE layout?

I'm also a little confused on the concept of getting the `context` of views and layouts... I probably misused it somewhere in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not in your current code.

Your `ColoredView` class currently extends `View`, which does not support having its own child Views. If you want to add child views to it, you will have to create a class extending `ViewGroup` (or any of ViewGroup's subclasses).

Once your class extends `ViewGroup`, you can simple use the `addView()` method to add Views, and align them by passing `LayoutParams` (you can also create custom `LayoutParams` if your view requires complex positioning).

Comment: I changed `extends View` to `extends ViewGroup` and it added the onLayout method. This is still pretty difficult to do, could you give me any examples or a link to a tutorial? I'm not entirely sure what to search for- there are so many things going on at once.

Comment: Also, do I use `addView()` in the `onLayout` Override or in another part of the class?